# how i can load form with initial data?

Tags: django, django-forms

I create custom UserChangeForm and I set all field to required=False and then when the user changes one field in that form all information in database change and if the user leaves one field, its update that field to empty. I need only change the field that the user entered in the form and other fields don't change in the database.

I tried :

```
    class UserInfoChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

        last_name = forms.CharField(label="",max_length=100,required=False)
        username = forms.CharField(label="", required=False)
        channel_name = forms.CharField(label="",max_length=100,required=False)

        class Meta:
            model = CustomUser
            fields = ('username', 'channel_name','last_name')

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           '
            super(UserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields.pop('password', 'email')
```

my views.py :

```
def update(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = UserInfoChangeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = UserInfoChangeForm()
    return render(request,'home/update.html',{'userupdate':UserInfoChangeForm})
```

Comment: Can you post your views.py method that manages this operation?

Comment: You could also just set all other fields to "disabled".

Comment: @TajinderSingh i update my post .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to override the form init, you can overwrite the form save method instead so that you only update the fields you want.

For example:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    if self.is_valid():
        # Get instance with self.instance & only update if a value's changed:
        for field_name in self.fields:
            if getattr(self.instance, field_name) != self.cleaned_data[field_name]:
                setattr(self.instance, field_name, self.cleaned_data[field_name])
                self.instance.save()
    return self.instance
```

Comment: i dont understand what you say ?

Comment: I am suggesting overwriting the save method in the UserInfoChangeForm class so that you only update the entity field value that was changed.

Comment: @s.Soroush "some_field" was just a place holder. You could just iterate over all your form's fields and check if it has been updated in the form. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the instance of the model to the form so that it will populate all of the fields with the existing values. That way it's up to the user to change whichever fields they would like. The other benefit of this is that it allows the user to clear out a field's value if they want to.

```
def update(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = UserInfoChangeForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = UserInfoChangeForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request,'home/update.html', {'userupdate': UserInfoChangeForm})
```

Comment: I use this method you said , but its not fill any field , mate i use AbstractUser to create new user model , but in view i print request.user and its return true information about user ,